# Google Analytics 4 - 'Conversions' bug in API? (Rows/records dropping with more dimensions)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I noticed an extremely odd interaction with the metric 'Conversions' in the API. It looks like the more dimensions we add to the data source, the less rows/records of conversions we get from the API.

I am sharing 4 screenshots:

1. LookerStudio - showing full amount of conversions.
   [Full amount of Conversions on Looker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw9MS.png)
2. API connector to GA's API using Tableau - with only 'Date' as a dimension, and 'Conversion' as a metric.
   [Full amount of Conversions on Tableau, with only 1 dimension (date)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASLva.png)
3. Same as 2) but with 2 dimensions ('Date' and a custom event dimension), and only 'Conversion' as a metric.
   [Less Conversions / missing rows or records?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRBym.png)
4. Same as 3) but with 3 dimensions ('Date', custom event, and 'sessionDefaultChannelGroup'), and only 'Conversion' as a metric.
   [Even less Conversions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNNsS.png)

I am not adding the dimensions into the visualisation - they are only part of the data source pull, so I am confused as to where the drop/segmentation/gap is happening.

I tried troubleshooting this in both Tableau's direct API connector (https://exchange.tableau.com/en-gb/products/867) and through an API connector flowing data into an AWS database using Redshift. The results were virtually the same between both platforms.